# ivyde isn't triggered to resolve on ivy.xml update from source control

Tags: eclipse, perforce, ivyde

When I refresh my project from source control (e.g., perforce), and I get an updated ivy.xml file, ivyde isn't triggered to do a "resolve".  So as a workaround, I do both a project refresh, and a manual ivyde resolve.

Is there a way to get ivyde to automatically resolve a new ivy.xml coming from source control?

- ivyde does do a resolve when I change my local ivy.xml.

Answer (score 0):

IvyDE depends on the files viewed by Eclipse itself. So no matter what, you'll have to do a refresh of your files in Eclipse.

Then, IvyDE is actually able to launch a resolve on an update of an ivy.xml file. Maybe in your configuration it is disabled. See http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/preferences.html